# Algolia Instantsearch - show real html content in react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, algolia

i configured a demo app in react with an algolia search.
I indexed some indices in algolia. The content is raw html.
Is it possible to render this content with algolia in real html?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the solution. I thought it its possible with the escapeHTML:false parameter of agnolia itself. A code snippet how this works, would be great.

Until there is no answer. I would use the native solution of react.

```
const Hit = ({hit})  =>
<div className="hit>">
<div className="title">
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:hit.content }}></div>
</div>
</div>
```